# Redirect robot.api.logger calls to file as messages are invisible due to XML-RPC

Tags: robotframework, python-decorators, xml-rpc, python-logging, robotframework-pythonremoteserver

In one of my projects we are using Robot Framework with custom keyword libraries in a complex test environment using assorted ECUs and PCs. One keyword library must be controlled by a python remote server via XML-RPC, as it has to be on a different PC.

Now, all important messages from robot.api.logger calls, like `logger.debug()` oder `logger.console()` are swallowed due to the XML-RPC. This is a known issue, which also clearly stated in the [docs](https://github.com/robotframework/PythonRemoteServer).

> For most parts these APIs work exactly like when using with Robot
> Framework normally. There main limitation is that logging using
> robot.api.logger or Python's logging module is currently not
> supported.

It is possible to write a thin wrapper or decorator for `robot.api.logger`, so that all debug messages are redirected to a simple txt file, like:

```
DEBUG HH:MM:SS > Message
WARN  HH:MM:SS > Message
```

This would be really helpful in case of problems.

Of course, it would be easy to use the built python logging module, but
I'm looking to find a solution, that changes the least amout of already existing code and I also want that the results are written to the text file additional to normal robot.api.logging to the Robot reports, as we are using the same library in a local and a remote way.

So basically I need to find a way to extend/redirected `robot.api.logger` calls, by first using the normal python logging module and then using the normal `robot.api.logger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can patch the [write](https://robot-framework.readthedocs.io/en/v3.1.2/autodoc/robot.api.html#robot.api.logger.write) function of the `robot.api.logger` so it will write to a log file as well. This patching could be triggered by a library argument.
This would require you to only modify the constructor of your library.

RemoteLib.py

```py
import sys

from robot.api import logger
from robot.output import librarylogger

from robotremoteserver import RobotRemoteServer
   
def write(msg, level='INFO', html=False):
    librarylogger.write(msg, level, html)
    with open('log.txt', 'a') as f:
        print(f'{level}\tHH:MM:SS > {msg}', file=f)
    

class RemoteLib():
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = 'GLOBAL'
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_VERSION = 0.1
    
    def __init__(self, to_file=True):
        if to_file:
            logger.write = write
        
    def log_something(self, msg):
        logger.info(msg)
        logger.debug(msg)
        logger.warn(msg)
        logger.trace(msg)
        logger.error(msg)
        logger.console(msg)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    RobotRemoteServer(RemoteLib(), *sys.argv[1:])
```

---

local_run.robot

```py
*** Settings ***
Library    RemoteLib    to_file=False

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Log Something    something
```

---

remote_run.robot

```py
*** Settings ***
Library       Remote    http://127.0.0.1:8270

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    Log Something    something
```

You could use the Python logging module as well in the `write` patch just as it is used in Robot Framework itself, [Redirects the robot.api.logger to python logging if robot is not running](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/commit/2d0e00c297747af99738e125d1359a8bc73bc908).